# Setting .attributedText on properties (accessible via outlets inside NIB-loaded UIView) from external reference appears to fail

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, nib

A nib has been loaded manually via `UINib(nibName, bundle).instantiate()`.

The outlets connecting the nib to a `UIView` subclass are being successfully initialized and are accessible.

Two of these outlets represent a `UILabel` and a `UITextView` - which are being used to present attributed text strings.

Changes to the attributed strings are being performed on mutable copies before replacement via the `.attribtedText` setter method.

Everything works as expected whenever functions intended to update the attributed text are called either directly in the UIView subclass or the View Controller that loads the nib.

However, when the same function is called via a reference kept inside some other class object elsewhere in the codebase, the updates don't happen.

The Nib's UIView subclass:

```
class MyView: UIView {            

    @IBOutlet weak var aLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var someText: UITextView!

    ...

    public func applySomeStyle() {

        guard
            let aLabelMAS = aLabel.attributedText?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString,
            var someTextMAS = someText.attributedText.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableAttributedString
        else {
            return
        }

        let labelRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: aLabelMAS.length)
        aLabelMAS.addAttribute(.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow, range: labelRange)

        let someTextRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: someTextMAS.length)
        someTextMAS.removeAttribute(.backgroundColor, range: someTextRange)

        aLabel.attributedText = aLabelMAS
        someText.attributedText = someTextMAS

    }

    public func doStuff() {

        ...

        applySomeStyle() // No problems -- the attributed strings inside the UILabel and UITextView are updated as intended.

        ...
    }

}
```

From inside the `ViewController` that loads the Nib, calls to the `applySomeStyle` function via the reference to the `MyView` object work fine.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var myView: MyView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        myView = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiate(
                withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? MyView
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
        ...
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        myView.applySomeStyle()  // Again, no problems.
    }

}
```

But if the nib class object is referenced elsewhere -- the changes don't occur.

```
class SomeOtherViewController: UIViewController

    var myVC: MyViewController!

    ...


    func foo() {
        myVC.myView.applySomeStyle() // Fails to update the UILabel/UITextView
    }


    ...

}
```

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I forgot that setting the attributedText property on the outlets triggers a call to viewDidLayoutSubview, which was reinstating some styles that I was looking to change in another function.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the `attributedText` setter, i.e.

`someText.attributedText = someNewAttributedString`

triggers `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, I was calling a function (e.g. a 'load content' function) that was also responsible for setting some string attributes. I was using a boolean flag to ensure that subsequent calls to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` weren't going to trigger that function again.

In this case, that boolean condition was not working as it was intended to, and so other functions that set the `attributedText` property were leading it to be triggered again, overwriting the changes made by other functions.

I thought I was dealing with an obscure bug.
I thought maybe it was a thread issue.
I thought maybe it was a broken reference of some kind.

I thought wrong.

But I hope that this proves useful to someone out there.